# how can we add and replace tags in php

Tags: php

i want insert tags in my string. which can be replaced later. for e.g.

```
$msg = "This message was sent [tag replaced later] at []";
```

is there any way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Look into [str_replace](http://it2.php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 2):

use str_replace..

```
$tags = array(
 '[a_tag]',
 '[another_tag]'
);
$replacements = array(
  'replace a tag',
  'replace another tag'
);

$string = 'I want to [a_tag] and [another_tag]';
$string = str_replace($tags, $replacements,$string);

echo $string;
```

Comment: alternatively, you can use `$tags = array('[a_tag]' => 'replace a tag', '[another_tag]' => 'replace another tag'); str_replace(array_keys($tags), array_values($tags), $string);`